# SSIS send mail for errors

Tags: ssis

How can I send emails with error details if there is any error in package execution?
Basically how can I get error details and put them in Message of Send mail task?

Comment: Three questions on the same topic, you don't accept the good answers you have, you just restate the question and ask again... WHY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the example :

Let's say i have one sql task , i want to get the email on "task failure" with the description of error .

1. Now drag the email task and give precedent constraint from *sql task to email task* on failure .
2. With in email task , give smtp connection, from, to email address , subject , message .. etc
3. Create the user variables for error message
4. Set the event handler for task failed or on error and create the script task with in package level .
5. In script task .. we need to assign the system variables and user variables .
6. Make sure the properties -- disable event handler should be false then only it will read the system variables .

Finally execute the package .. if any error occurred then you will get the email with the description .

Thanks

R

Answer (score 2):

This is what we do. We use the logging system of SSIS to log all errors to a table.

Then create an event handler at the package level. IN the event handler I send an email when something fails that contains the name of the package (which we always havea as a variable), the name of the task that failed (use variable System::SourceName for this, took me a while to find it.) and a query of the logging tables to enable the support team to quickly pull up the details (part of the body of the email, I use a variable but you don't have to).

Comment: System::PackageName also holds the name of the package, so you don't need to create a variable to hold it. If you are using the default logging format, your log query will be "Select * from dbo.sysdtslog90 where executionID = " along with the value of System:ExecutionInstanceGuid. ** These variable and table names valid in Sql Server 2005 may be different in other versions**

Comment: We do because we have names in our our meta data database that may not exactly match the package name and I need to use that name. And our queries are differnt because we parse out the logging information into a more user friendly format in our meta database.  But your point is exactly correct if you aren't using a customized meta database, William.