# SSIS - Determine which tasks failed, send single email with details

Tags: c#, ssis

I've got a simple package which updates my database then exports data to five different files. What I'm trying to do is produce an email which details whether each of the exports have run successfully. So I want something like this in the email:

```
|EXPORT | STATUS  |
| 4     | Success |
| 5     | Success |
| 6     | Success |
| 7     | Failed  |
| 8     | Success |
```

Initially, I had separate Success and Fail (`Logical OR`) email tasks set up. This allowed me to determine that either all the tasks succeeded or at least one failed... but that wasn't what I wanted.

Then, I looked at [this example](http://geekswithblogs.net/LifeLongTechie/archive/2009/09/11/to-capture-all-errors-in-an-ssis-package.aspx) and rewriting it in C# within my script task, but I realised that the variables in the example didn't seem to exist (script would throw an error), so I tried creating user variables and passing them through in the `ReadWriteVariables`, the script would run successfully but nothing would be displayed in the Send Mail Task, the the script wasn't actually doing anything.

I've looked at a few similar questions and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460117/ssis-send-mail-for-errors) *seems* to be close to what I want, it kind of explains *what to do*, but doesn't really help a beginner like myself to actually do it.

**Here's my Control Flow for reference:**

[image: My Control Flow]

**And the `Main` method within the script task:**

```
ArrayList messages = new ArrayList();

try 
{
    messages = (ArrayList) Dts.Variables["ErrorCollection"].Value;
} 
catch (Exception Ex) 
{
    // Handle errors...
}

messages.Add(Dts.Variables["ErrorDescription"].Value.ToString());
Dts.Variables["ErrorCollection"].Value = messages;
Dts.Variables.Unlock();
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

I don't know whether I'm going about this the wrong way, there's probably an easy way to do this but being new to SSIS I don't know what it is. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Right, I managed to figure it out on my own. For anyone facing a similar problem, here's how I went about it:

1. Set up a variable for each task you want to monitor - this could be a `1` or `0` for success/failure. In my case I set the variables for each task to a default success message string.
2. Apply an `OnError` event handler to each task you want to monitor
3. Place an `Expression Task` within the `OnError` handler and use it to set your variable to the fail condition. E.g. `@[User:YourVariable] = "Failed"`
4. Within a `Send Mail Task` you can concatenate each of the variables you created earlier for the `MessageSource` within the Expressions tab of the Send Mail Task editor.

This solution skips the `Script Task` altogether, but if you wanted to build up a more detailed email message, you could pass the variables to a Script instead of straight into the Send Mail Task.

Comment: Well done for posting your solution I'm sure people will find this helpful. . Alternatively: All task failures are written to SSISDB (assuming this is the correct version of SSIS). You can write one query which gets the latest execution and any errors from SSISDB and emails them off, rather than hand coding a whole harness in the package. The advantage is you can add as many additional steps as you want in your package without needing to add custom code.